# Using canvas animation as background

Tags: php, css, animation, iframe

I've made a flipping animation that I want to use for background of my website. I've set the canvas size to 1280*800 and saved it as a webpage. I tried to use an iframe and let the browser scale it to fit (100%;100%), but it's not working very well. Since the body is set to 950px and auto margin, the iframe will only align to as left as the left side of the body, and the iframe did not scale with zooming in/out.

Is there a better way to do this than using iframes? Php or js?

The reason I've saved the animation as a separate webpage is because I felt I made it have too many lines (~1100), there are basically 20 or so of the same flipping animation, and I didn't know a better way other than just to do them individually and use style to place them around.

Comment: Please tell me your website address, so I can blacklist it on my machine. Sounds like it'll give me seizures.

Comment: Code please! Also what are you trying to achieve? A few things sound wrong about this.

Comment: Did you achieve something smooth on mobile using a canvas animation in background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your questions correctly, you'll want to add the `canvas` element to a div layer that has `#canvasDiv { position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1; }` and give everything else a z-index of 2 or greater.

Checkout http://paulirish.com/
to check out a great code example of how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for an actual answer! I've figured it out, and that was not the problem actually. I've only set the z-index to -1 on the background div, since everything else is by default 0 I believe. But thanks for the link, here's another one that helped me: http://radikalfx.com/2009/10/17/html5-animated-background/

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue or not, but setting something to a negative z-index will cause it to go below clickable space. So if it's an interactive Canvas element, they won't be able to interact with it. Just a word of warning :-)